# Spring Security userCache invalidation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cache-control

Using Spring Security I have a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` described like here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/dao-provider.html

I also have caching (also like it's described in that article).

The problem is that when a request comes in with a good username (that is already in the cache), but a bad password - it returns the user from the cache as if it is a good username/password. Because it uses the username as the key, the password is not involved at all.

The exact code that returns the user from the cache:

```
UserDetails user = this.userCache.getUserFromCache(username);
```

Did anybody ever dealt with this problem before? I can also check if the password is the same, but it would be a custom thing.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the username and password sent per request?  If so, I guess caching does not make sense.

Comment: It makes sense if you want to save on DAO calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configured your application with the standard components, the scenario should be as follows:

1. At user request arrival the `Authentication` object is created and populated with username and password supplied by user.
2. User details are retrieved: if it's possible, `UserCache` is used to retrieve previously cached user details (i.e. `getUserFromCache` is called either by implementations of `UserDetailsService` or `AuthenticationProvider` *before* the call to `AuthenticationManager` is performed). And it is 100% OK that the user details from cache will come with the good password.
3. After basic pre-authentication checks (credentials expiration etc.) the actual authentication occurs. At this point the password from cached user details is compared to the password stored in `Authentication` object supplied (which currently contains the wrong password). At this point authentication attempt fails.

However, if you implement *your own* `AuthenticationProvider` or `AuthenticationManager`, you are responsible for password checking.

Comment: In the end I did have to do my own password checking, since I had a custom AuthenticationProvider. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the code that originally gets the user from the DB and caches it?  Does it check the password?  Sounds like you have an abstraction issue - Spring Security should not know where the user is coming from (DB or Cache) and should use the same logic either way.

Comment: Yes, that originally gets the password and caches the user object (along with the password). But when a following request comes along, Spring checks if the user is cached, based on the username, if it's in the cache it assumes that the authentication is successful. That is the problem.